# Winform application freeze

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Winform application,which does some operation in loops (file access, copy file, ....). During theses operation, the application freeze completely, the job is done but impossible to move the **main window** or refresh the `RichTextBox` information (we display errors and the job in progress).

Do you have an idea how to do this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Possibly duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737088/winforms-avoid-freeze-application?rq=1

Use background worker, Tasks or just traditionnal Threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using BackgroundWorker.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

It can both run your code in the background and report progress back to to the main 
UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest that you use a Background Worker and let the worker do the loops. i think your application read a file by line and added to the rich textbox control right?

this article will guide you in using [BackGround Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). or [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate thread and execute other task or may use background worker thread.